# Do these clear functions do the same thing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

So do these two functions accomplish the same thing in C++?

```
void MYCLASS::clear() {
classSize = 0;
class_ptr = NULL;
}

void MYCLASS::clear() {
classSize = 0;
*class_ptr = NULL;
}
```

Where `int *class_ptr` is declared in my header file. When I hover my mouse over Visual Studio shows class_ptr as the same type.

I believe that they are both pointing class_ptr at NULL. However, I want to make sure that they are indeed both doing this.

Comment: nope.  The first sets a pointer to NULL, and one sets the object being pointed at to NULL.  It's like the difference between destroying directions to a house, and destroying the house.

Comment: Mooing Duck, I love that analogy. That really sticks. Would this result in a memory leak?

Comment: Neither example has `delete` nor `free`, so both leak.

Comment: @lemmalemma: if you set `class_ptr` to null without calling `delete` and it pointed to an area of dynamically allocated memory, yes, it would be a leak.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The second does not necessarily contain a leak (though, judging by the name of the function, it probably does).  That chunk of memory was modified, but you can still call `delete` on the pointer and reclaim it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I believe that they are both pointing class_ptr at NULL.

Nope...

```
class_ptr = NULL;
```

Sets the pointer's value to `NULL`, i.e., `class_ptr == NULL`.

```
*class_ptr = NULL;
```

Sets *what `class_ptr` refers (points) to to `NULL`*, which is `0`.  `class_ptr` itself retains its value.

A pointer's value is an address.  What resides at that address is (should be) a representation of the type of the pointer itself, i.e.,

```
int *p = new int(10);
/* ... */
 p  <-- an address, let's say, 0x0000F8BE
*p  <-- an int, 10
```

Note that, if there existed no implicit conversion from `int` (`NULL` has a value of `0`) to whatever type `class_ptr` refers to, the code wouldn't even compile (which leads me to believe that this particular pointer is poorly named).

---

EDIT: I liked @Mooing Duck's analogy so much that I stole it (he has not posted an answer, so I don't think he'll mind).

> It's like the difference between destroying directions to a house, and destroying the house.

Comment: In reality I'm not happy with the analogy, because "destroying the house" implies a lot of things that don't happen.  But yeah, I don't mind being quoted.  Maybe covering an address in whiteout compared to covering a house in whiteout?  Because it's still a house, you just screwed it up.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Haha, well... I think it gets the point of cross well enough.

Answer (score 2):

No, they're not doing the same. This:

```
class_ptr = NULL;
```

Effectively sets the pointer to `NULL`.

This on the other hand:

```
*class_ptr = NULL;
```

Sets the content of the address pointed by `class_ptr` to `NULL`. In this case, since `class_ptr` is of type `int*`, and `NULL` is defined as the integral value `0`, you are setting the content of the pointer to `0`.

Comment: "content of the pointer" is a really bad way to describe it.  It's the content pointed-to, which is distinct from the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're different. The first one sets the pointer to NULL. The second one sets WHAT IT IS POINTING AT to null

Comment: So the second one would set the integer being pointed at to 0 while the first would just point the pointer to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

No, these lines aren't the same.

`class_ptr = NULL;` sets the pointer to 0. The actual integer (where the pointer points to) isn't modified. You're just losing the pointer.

`*class_ptr = 0;` will dereference the pointer and set the actual integer's value to 0. You're keeping the pointer and it's still valid after this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the two pieces of code are distinctly different, they do two different things.  The first seems the most likely to be correct for a clear function.  Given the second is setting the value the pointer is pointing two, it is ambiguous to be setting it to NULL.  While it compiles (NULL = 0), it looks wrong and so probably is.

My guess is that the first one is what you intended.

Comment: *"Given the two pieces of code are distinctly different, they do two different things"* - Not true at all.  There are often many ways of getting the same result (not the case here of course).

Comment: Sorry, my wording was a bit loose.  I was really referring to the obvious difference (dereference on one, not the other).  I was trying to say that there was no way they could be doing the same thing.  A bit like "x + y", "x - y".  You can get the same answer in some situations, but they are definitely not doing the same thing.